# How to use env attribute of Vagrant Docker provider?

Tags: environment-variables, vagrant, docker

I want to change an environment-variable of a docker container with the Vagrant Docker provisioner. How can I do this?

Example Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.define 'container' do |ws|
    ws.vm.hostname = 'container'
    ws.ssh.port = 23
    ws.ssh.guest_port = 23
    ws.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.image = "name/image"
      d.env = {
        "SSH_PORT" => 23
      }
      d.vagrant_machine = "host"
      d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "../Vagrantfile"
      d.force_host_vm = true
      d.has_ssh = true
    end
end
```

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:centos7
ENV PORT 22
#...
RUN echo "Port $PORT" >>  /somefile.txt
#...
EXPOSE $PORT
```

It's always ending up with PORT=22 instead of 23.
A possible workaround with `d.create_args = ["-e", "PORT=23"]` failed too.

Sources:
[Vagrant Docker](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/docker/configuration.html)
[Docker environment-vars](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#env-environment-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `ENV PORT 22` in your `Dockerfile`, it will be defined as such and not inherited from the build environment. If you wish to override it, you could do that while running the container: `docker run --rm -it -e PORT=23 <your image> env | grep PORT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `d.env` part:

```
d.env = {
        "SSH_PORT":"23"
}
```

Comment: This can't be used in the Docker provisioner. It can only be used in the [Docker provider](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/docker/index.html). There is a huge difference between those two.

Comment: This does not work. I have tried this: dev.vm.provider :docker do |d, override|
      d.image = "foo"
      d.name = "bar"
      d.cmd = ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
      d.pull = true
      d.env = {"USER" : "root"} end I get syntax error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
      d.env = {"USER" : "root"}